# Jquery: conditionally add class if the url contains a specific hash value

Tags: jquery, hash, conditional-statements

How can I add a conditional statement that says something like

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#/brandpartners"))
    {
    $("#brandpartners").addClass("specialbrand");
    }
```

The hash seems to break the statement. Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "The hash"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can't use indexOf that way.  It returns -1, when it's not found which isn't false.

It makes a lot more sense to me to just use the built-in parsing of the hash value in the location object.  I'd suggest doing it this way:

```
if (window.location.hash == "#brandpartners") {
    $("#brandpartners").addClass("specialbrand");
}
```

I don't know your URL structure, but there shouldn't be a need for a slash after the # for a simple hash value.  But, if you insist on using the slash, it would look like this:

```
if (window.location.hash == "#/brandpartners") {
    $("#brandpartners").addClass("specialbrand");
}
```

Comment: he probably is using a hash because he's loading in page content from the /brandpartners page via an xhr request. The rest of your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

The hash (`#`) isn't breaking the statement at all for me. But I don't know exactly why you have the `/` in there when you don't need it.

```
var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950161#hmenus";
alert(str.indexOf("#hmenus"));
```

This code alerts 42, which means it should do what you want. I

Answer (score 1):

As @jfriend00 sais, it should be:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#/brandpartners")!=-1)
            {
$("#brandpartners").addClass("specialbrand");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf()` returns -1 if the string is not found, which evaluates as "truthy" such that your `if` statement isn't doing what you think it is. So try:

`if (window.location.href.indexOf("#/brandpartners") != -1) {}`